# What is wrong with this example of class inheritance?

Tags: php, oop, php-7.3

This code of dependency inversion should work fine but instead it gives error.

What am I doing wrong in here?

```
interface A  { }

abstract class B implements A { }

class C extends B { }

abstract class D {
    public function foo(A $a) { }
}

class E extends D {
    public function foo(C $c) { }
}
```

The error is:

> **Warning**:  Declaration of E::foo(C $c) should be compatible with D::foo(A $a) in **[...][...]** on line **24**

Surprisingly, doing the same for the constructor method works just fine:

```
interface A  { }

abstract class B implements A { }

class C extends B { }

abstract class D {
    public function __construct(A $a) { }
    public function foo(A $a) { }
}

class E extends D {
    public function __construct(C $c) { }
    public function foo(A $c) { }
}
```

Comment: I tested here with 7.3.5 http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f1c4b7f631c8cf42ff38e1728625435589f136e6

Comment: not quite. in this case the argument is contravariant. abstract class D accepts everything that is a subtype above A. B is a subtype of A, C is a subtype of B which is a subtype of A, so in this case A is the last specific type so it must accept everything above it.

Comment: so why in the constructor everything is ok? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9d75058fba9a6ca6e9a13c1c4d74814e70ec0c99

Answer (score 3):

There are two questions here.

Why the first part raises a `WARNING`: the error is pretty explicit. Any time you override a method you need to respect the parent's signature, so a client application's expectations are met.

```
class Foo {}

class Bar extends Foo {}

class A {
   public function test(Foo $foo) {}
}

class B extends A {
   public function test(Bar $bar) {}
}
```

Now, since `B` extends `A`, and `A::test()` expects a `Foo`, a user might try to do this:

```
$a = new A();
$b = new B();

$foo = new Foo();
$bar = new Bar();

$b->test($bar);
$b->test($foo);
```

The first call to `test()` would work, but the second would fail (and fatally): a `Foo` is not a `Bar`.

The parameter type is **more restrictive** than the original, and thus breaks expectations from client applications. Note that if we had a legal declaration (`B::test(Foo)`), we could still call `$b->test($bar)` and would work as expected, so changing the signature is not really necessary.

In November 2019, When PHP 7.4 is released, [**contravariance** will be supported for parameter types, and covariance will be supported for return types](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/covariant-returns-and-contravariant-parameters); so your example would still be invalid.

Finally, notice that the error raised is a `WARNING`, it won't crash the program immediately. But it is warning you that you are opening your application to behaviour that **might** crash it, and that's it's generally poor design (for the reasons explained above).

---

The second question: Why you do not get the same warning for the constructor? They do not raise this warning by design. If you check the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#object.construct), you'll find this:

> Unlike with other methods, PHP will not generate an E_STRICT level error message when __construct() is overridden with different parameters than the parent __construct() method has.

Why constructors are treated differently? Because it is generally understood that constructors are not part of the "public API" of an object, and do not need to be subjected to the same constraints. The [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) deals with objects, not with classes; and before an class is instantiated there is yet no object. Thus, the constructor is out of scope.

You can read more about this [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/178888/257074), for example.

Comment: Your argument explains that "a user might want to try to do something wrong" which is totally fine to break the code and raise an error. But the declaration has not yet an implementation and no code written yet to call the method. Are those methods aware of the wrong things that the user might try to do in the future? As long as the C implements A it is expected to have the methods that are required by contract so D can't be worried that C won't have some method that is needed because that's how things work: C must have all the methods in A. Is not this correct?

Comment: No, it is not correct. If C overrides a method on A, the method needs to be compatible. A more restrictive declaration is not compatible.

Comment: Luckyboy, since it appears to be new at SO: it's customary to "accept" an answer if it resolves the issue raised in the question. I think my answer addresses every point in your question. (The other answer is also good). Consider accepting an answer, if you wish.

Comment: Not every answer should be acceptable without any further clarification. So I would ask you to clarify why C could override the interface as long as its contract is by definition immutable. That would be my final question about that.

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is unclear. C cannot "override" the interface. It can _implement_ an interface. It can override a method implementation. It can override the method signature only if the signature is compatible with the signature of the overridden method.

Comment: You said that is not correct because if C overrides a method on A the methods should be compatibile. What method exactly overrided C in my example to make the declation of E fail? As I pointed out D should not worry that C would not have the methods of A and even if C would override the implementation as long as the signature is the same what seems to be the problem more exactly because that is not clarified yet on my example code?

Comment: In your example `E:foo()` overrides `D::foo()`. And the method is not compatible. The error message told you so, and I explained you why. I'm sorry but I'm having trouble understanding you. Not sure I will be able to help you further.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR `C` is implementing `A`, but it can also inherit other methods from `B` which implementing `A` doesn't guarantee. This creates situation where two classes of same inherited type can have two methods with different signatures. **A sub-class must accept all inputs that the parent class would accept, but it can accept additional inputs if it wants,**

Let's extend your example.

Nothing crazy, just some example methods.

```
interface A
{
    public function gotA();
}

abstract class B implements A
{
    abstract public function gotB();
}

class C extends B
{
    public function gotA()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public function gotB()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I can agree that `C` is indirectly implementing `A`, but it also contains methods from `B`, so the call in `E::foo()` would be perfectly fine.

```
abstract class D
{
    public function foo(A $a)
    {
        $a->gotA();
    }
}

class E extends D
{
    public function foo(C $c)
    {
        $c->gotB();
    }
}
```

Another example class implementing `A`.

```
class ExampleA implements A
{
    public function gotA()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now the fun part. Assume this function anywhere else in your code. It assumes `D` (expecting `A` in `foo`) as parameter.

But `E` is also `instanceof D` and can be passed to `x`, but it expects `C` in `foo` which `ExampleA` has nothing to do with.

```
function x(D $d)
{
    $exampleA = new ExampleA();
    $d->foo($exampleA);
}


$e = new E();
x($e);
```

To sum up, the contract for function `x` has been met and yet the function broke.

You ended up with two 'different' `D` types. The one expecting `A` and the one expecting `C`.

As for why it doesn't throw warning with `__constructor` I don't know. Need further investigation.

Comment: as long as you can't explain about the constructor your explanation fails as we have a contra-argument that disagrees with the theory. like in any science.

Comment: your explanation is valid on why the code will fail when it is wrongly used (when you inject ExampleA in E), not on why the declaration is wrong in the first place.